# Oracle JDeveloper can't open java file?

Tags: java, macos, jdeveloper

I am new to Oracle JDeveloper. I can't open java file in project.

When I opening project JDeveloper showing error:

[image]

When i want open java file JDeveloper showing error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: AddinLibrary instances are immutable.
```

[image: Sowing this]

How to fix this ?

I'm using Mac os (Catalina 10.15.1) and JDeveloper (Version 12.2.1.4.0) .
java version 1.8.0_191

Comment: Is this happening with all files or just one specific file?

Answer (score 0):

this might not be the full remedy to your above issue, however, It might be cache issue, not sure about it, you can give it a try.

1. Completely removing all existing $MW_HOME/.jdeveloper/system12.*/system_cache folders.
2. remove /.jdeveloper/12.* folders and restart JDeveloper

NOTE:Sometimes these errors might not be related to anything we would think, it might be something related to mentioned above.